# Remote Docker only Binds to tcp6

Tags: docker, docker-api, docker-daemon

So I wanted to enable remote docker, to use the API for the daemon from outside the host.

My `/etc/docker/daemon.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

And my `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/options.conf` looks like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

When i try to list all Containers using the curl command on the host with localhost it works:

`curl localhost:2375/v1.38/containers/json`

i get a json-list of all Containers.
[]

But if i try using:

`curl 10.1.44.11:2375/v1.38/containers/json`

i only get a empty json  back:
[]

when i run:

`sudo netstat -ltnp | grep dockerd`

I get:

`tcp6       0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      xxx/dockerd`

I am kind of confused why it show tcp6 instead of tcp.

can someone help?

Comment: What is this IP address 10.1.44.11 which you have tried? is it available for ping command? If not check by adding this to your /etc/hosts file

Comment: @PavanDevarakonda 10.1.44.11, is the IP of the Host which the Docker daemon is running on, sorry for not specifying. the ping command works.

Do i have to make an entry in host file?